# Adding elements to elements in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been coding a database program that uses XML. Whenever the program boots and doesn't find the XML file at the path specified, it generates this:

```
<!--  Studnet Database  -->
<schoolDB>
    <Grades>
        <Grade10/>
        <Grade11/>
        <Grade12/>
    </Grades>
    <Employees/>
</schoolDB>
```

I want the program to add an `element` called `student` in the `Grade*` element (the user is prompted to enter a grade from 10 to 12 and then it parses that to Grade10 -> Grade12). I wrote this:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(prog.dbFile);
    doc.Element(toWriteGrade).Add(new XElement("student",
            new XElement("name", name),
            new XElement("age", age)));
    doc.Save(prog.dbFile);
```

When I run this, it gives me an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in StudentClone1.exe`
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

That means you are not selecting grade element correctly:

```
doc.Element(toWriteGrade) // this returns null
```

Thus grades are elements of `Grades` element, you should query it this way:

```
doc.Root.Element("Grades").Element(toWriteGrade)
```

Or (less efficient) you can just look through all elements in file:

```
doc.Descendants(toWriteGrade)
```

Comment: I thought `Root` would write it to the `schoolDB` element, I guess not. Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: @Ilan321 node.Element method just checks direct children of node. That's why you can't find grade element - it does not exist in doc direct children (only root element can be found there)

Comment: BTW I suggest you to use some `id` or `value` attribute for specifying grades instead of changing name of grade elements. I.e. instead of `<Grade10>` use `<Grade id='10/>` that will make querying easier